# R function or loop that could go through a binary variable (1 and 0) in a dataframe and returns a third variable (y) value from a different column

Tags: r, function, loops, row

I do need some help. 
 
 I am trying to build a function or a loop using `R` that could go through a binary variable (`1` and `0`) in a dataframe in such way that everytime 1 is followed by a `0`, I could save a vector indicating the value of a third variable (`y`)  in the same line where it occurred. 
 
 I tried a couple of options based on previous posts, but nothing gives me something even close from that.

My data looks a bit like that:

```
ID <- rep(1001, 5) 
variable <- c(1, 1, 0, 1, 0) 
y <- c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50) 
df <- cbind(ID, variable, y)
```

In this case, for example, the answer would give me a vector with the `y` values `30` and `50`. Sorry if someone already has answered that, I could not find something similar.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach with tidyverse:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  as.tibble %>%
  mutate(y1 = ifelse(lag(variable) == 1 & variable == 0, y, NA)) %>%
  pull(y1)
#output
[1] NA NA 30 NA 50
```

and in base R:

```
ifelse(c(NA, df[-nrow(df),2]) == 1 & df[, 2] == 0, df[, 3], NA)
```

if the lag of variable is 1 and the variable is 0 then return y, else return NA.

If you would like to remove the NA. wrap it in `na.omit`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a 'vectorial' solution. Basically, I paste together variable in position i and i+1. Then I check to see if the combination is "10". The position you want is actually the next one (e.g. i+1), so we add 1.

```
df <- data.frame(ID, variable, y) 
idx <- which(paste0(df$variable[-nrow(df)], df$variable[-1]) == "10") + 1
df$y[idx]
```